# How to hyphenate a capital word with CSS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, firefox, css-hyphens

I have one word I need to hyphenate, however in `lang=en` `hyphenate: auto` does not work on capital words.

So in js I used the slice function to slice the word in half so the second half that needs hyphenating no longer counts as a capital word.

However this solution works on Chrome but not Firefox.

I know German allows hyphenation of capital letters but I want to avoid changing the language.

Here is an example code snippet

```
let word = 'Exceptional'

<div>
<span class='hyphenate'>
{word.slice(0,1)}
{word.slice(1)}
<span>
<div>


.hyphenate {
display: 'flex'
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
}
```

In this code segment, if the div is too small, the word 'Exceptional' will be hyphenated automatically on every browser except Firefox.

Comment: Could you put up a small example of the code (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - I think you'll need to use CSS to convert the word but I'm not sure without seeing your particular use case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What's a "capital word,"? I'm assuming a proper noun (name), so "Bratislava," or "Chadhawarasamy" (to attempt to give examples of longish names).

Comment: I have added a code example

Comment: I don't see a runnable snippet in your question.

Comment: Are you using the lang attribute on your html tag? Language can help with hyphenation (among other things): https://adrianroselli.com/2015/01/on-use-of-lang-attribute.html

Answer (score -1):

I think that the CSS property that you are looking for is "hyphens" instead of "hyphenate". So try:

```css
.hyphenate {
display: flex;
hyphens: auto;
}
```

Try also to add these properties to maximize compatibility [as this reference explains:](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_hyphens.asp)

```css
.hyphenate {
display: flex;
hyphens: auto;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have made a typo. I used hypens: auto. 

So it works on chrome but not FF.

Comment: According to https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#hyphenation "a UA might try to avoid hyphenation in proper nouns by excluding words matching certain capitalization and punctuation patterns". IE, bad_coder is trying to create a workaround for what is essentially the browser not allowing hyphens when words are capitalized (or all UPPERCASE).